# Answer Hijacking; What's the proper course of action?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I know the "old-timers" response is, "Just move on...", but when you don't have enough user score to perform some of the functions here (like reviews, which requires a minimum score of 2K), every point is vital.

I answered this question at almost the exact same time as the other person:
[Data type mismatch using RND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548450/data-type-mismatch-using-rnd-in-access/17548646#17548646)

The problem is, after I answered it, the other person went back and added code to his answer.  His original answer was just the first paragraph.  He basically hijacked my answer, and got the points for it.

Is there some type of grievance system where you can submit this stuff for reviews?  I know that's probably more work than the mods need, but like I said these points are important while you're trying to earn the right to perform other functions on the site.

Comment: LitteBobbyTables' code doesn't look like your answer at all. What makes you think he copied your answer?

Comment: Just because someone has posted a similar answer doesn't mean that it's copied... they'll always get the benefit of the doubt (unless you can prove otherwise). I suspect LBT was busy editing during the first 5 minutes and didn't even see your answer.

Comment: It's actually quite similar.  Nearly identical, in fact.  To me, it's obvious he gave a quick answer, then saw mine was more detailed and so added code to it.

Comment: You came across a Fastest Gun in the West user: give a fast, short answer, then flesh it out. There is *absolutely no reason* to assume that he copied your answer.

Comment: The only similarity I see is that both answer the same question.

Comment: When I select a best answer, I choose what is actually the best answer and not who answered first, or who came up with the idea first. Even though the best answer might have taken some hints from other answers, for future visitors the best answer should be chosen.

Comment: This isn't the first time this has happened, it's just the first time I'm posting this question.  Let's say LBT was a Fastest Gun.  What do users do when it's obvious their answers WERE hijacked?  And don't act like it's never happened here...

Comment: @JohnnyBones - In reality even if correct and blatant there isn't much you can do about it. I've seen it happen once before that someone copied code from my answer right down to demo table names then changed the table names to something different when I posted a comment about it. All this happened within the 5 minute edit grace period so no audit trail.

Comment: Woo, first question directly about me!  @JohnnyBones - I apologize if you feel that I copied your answer, but I can assure you, *I did not*.  I had written the first sentence (`You need to verify the values in the Number column where a.Location = 'Columbus'... I suspect you have a non-numeric value in one of the Number columns, which is causing the type mismatch error.`), and then went back to double-check the syntax on `IsNumeric` before editing it into my answer.  Your answer wasn't there when I was editing my answer, but thanks for assuming I copied your answer.

Comment: This was one of the reasons for [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history), but it was declined.

Comment: @Aaron: And this question here only seems to confirm [my reasons for opposing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138067/56338).

Comment: @sth I understand it wouldn't *always* point out problems. But I still don't understand what harm it would cause. In this case, for example, the symptom was observed without my feature request being implemented, and nobody is denying that they changed the answer within the grace period.

Comment: I know how you feel, this happened to me once too. A guy gives a partial answer (almost non-answer actually); another guy adds something on the side. I come in and add answer much closer to what was asked; the first guy copies into his post from my and the other guy's, and gets above 10 upvotes after that, while we're stuck at 1 or 2! What can you do?.. as long as it's not a pattern. You could address them via comments... I actually stopped answering when I saw that guy's answer on a question. He's almost always the first to answer, and gets it right most of the time though.

Comment: I must add, he mentioned my answer in his edit.

Answer (score 21):

> ...but when you don't have enough user score to perform some of the functions here (like reviews, which requires a minimum score of 2K), every point is vital.

That sounds odd, you might want to rethink your view of SO. I don't say that reputation is not important, but you should for sure not claw for every single point. Sometimes your answer get's accepted, sometimes another, move on, keep writing good and awesome answers.

> I answered this question at almost the exact same time as the other person.

[Fastest Gun In The West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

> The problem is, after I answered it, the other person went back and added code to his answer.

Hey, people editing answers to make them better? Maybe based on other answers? That's awesome!

> He basically hijacked my answer, and got the points for it.

[Definition of "hijack" from Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hijack):

> 1. To forcibly stop and seize control of some vehicle in order to rob it or to reach a destination (especially an airplane, truck or a boat).
> 2. To seize control of some process or resource to achieve a purpose other than its originally intended one.
> 3. (computing) To seize control of a networked computer by means of infecting it with a worm or other malware, thereby turning it into a zombie.
> 4. (computing) To change software settings without a user's knowledge so as to force that user to visit a certain web site (to hijack a browser).
> 5. (politics) To introduce an amendment deleting the contents of a bill and inserting entirely new provisions.

I fail to see how anything from you is "hijacked"...sorry. I also fail to see anything past "inspiration" from your answer (means: it looks like LittleBobbyTables also did not copy anything from you, which would be okay, too, as long as it is attributed).

> Is there some type of grievance system where you can submit this stuff for reviews?

Why would you like to submit this for review? The process of

- Posting answer
- Realizing answer could be better
- Editing answer to make it better

is very normal on SE. Even if that means you realize that your answer could be better from looking at other answers.

Despite that I understand where you're coming from, I have to tell you that there's absolutely *nothing wrong* with what we see here.