# What to do in a such case if it seems that someone is missing to cite right

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across this question today and at first I thought that the the view had rendered twice the same answer: "[Does jQuery not work with id's sent over an Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733906/does-jquery-not-work-with-ids-sent-over-ajax-request)".

But then I realized that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734008/1456376) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733962/1456376) answers have the exact same explanation. At first I wanted to edit both posts and set the part as a quote as it might have been from the manual, and the respondents simply didn't distinguish that. But when [searching](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww#q=%22The%20solution%20to%20this%20is%20to%20use%20event%20delegation%2C%20in%20this%20model%20the%20handler%20is%20registered%20to%20a%20ancestor%20element%22) for the assumed quote I came up with two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370765/1456376)/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708881/1456376) that were made a couple of days ago by the user who also wrote one of the answers of the concrete question.

So it seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733962/1456376) is missing to cite right. What should I do in such a case:

- Edit this answer and set the explanation as a quote from one of the other user's answers?
- Add a comment, to please the author of the "*copy*" to set the explanation as a quote?
- Do nothing as the other author of the original text didn't add a comment himself?

I'm aware of *"[Is it okay to copy-paste answers from other questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78658/190341)"* and *"[Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24611/190341)"*, but I'm still not sure how to deal with such a case.

Comment: Related, possible Duplicates: [Answer Hijacking; What's the proper course of action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188022/answer-hijacking-whats-the-proper-course-of-action)

Comment: Rule of thumb: If a question attracts many short, similar looking answers, then there's something wrong with the question.

Comment: Another rule of thumb: if you can copy and paste the answer, you probably should have just voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: True that, both rules of thumb are very good. But please note that the question is meant from an editor/reviewer point of view and not from the person who actually answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel [this perfectly answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/24618#24618) your question.

Let me just quote the original author: [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
>
> - **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> - **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> - **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> - **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a [TinyURL][13] URL or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must *not* be [nofollowed][5].

---

So my suggestion in your case is:

- Submit an edit to the answer and link it to the original answer.
- You may want to indicate who the original author is.
- leave a comment in the Edit summary textbox linking it to this meta
  question.

Comment: +1 The first part of your answer is clear. My uncertainty was about how to deal with it. I guess editing is the method of choice so I'll go with it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see how that applies here. In the example @insertusernamehere shows in the first paragraph, the answers are most likely not copied from each other but created separately. The code is copied from the OP question. There is no attribution to follow, as they are the genuine authors of their answers, or at least we should assume that if in doubt.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby the answers are exactly the same starting at *"When you use a normal event registration model..."*.

Comment: @mehow: Argh, sorry, I assumed it was a quote from that link. In that case it applies, yes.